# How to migrate this regex to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex that works perfectly with PHP:

```
$que = preg_replace("/(?<=^| )([a-z])\\1*(?= |$)\K|([a-z])(?=\\2)/","$3",$que);
```

This regex removes repeated chars inside strings (for example, `axxd` becomes `axd` however `xxx` will still become `xxx`). The problem that I am facing, is because it does not work with JS (I think the negative lookbehind does not work with JS).

More examples:

1. the string `aaa baaab xxx` would become `aaa bab xxx`
2. the string `ahhj aaab cc iiik` would become `ahj ab cc ik`

Do you have a solution for this that is at least a little efficient? I mean, I will probably use this regex on a string with 1k chars, so if the regex is not efficient, the browser may freeze.

Comment: There is no group 3 in the original regex. Also, please explain what the difference between the examples is.

Comment: There is a group 3, it works perfectly with PHP. I just tried it. I will add more examples

Comment: @Samul no, there isn't a group 3, so you are basically replacing your match with an empty string. Try changing `"$3"` to `""` and you'll see you get the same result.

Comment: Though not your question, for PHP consider the regex, `\b(.)\1*\b\K|(.)(?=\2)`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/99jUIi/1)

Comment: For JS (with a bit of code), you could convert all *single-character* matches of the following regular expression to an empty string: `\b(.)\1+\b|(.)(?=\2)` (i.e., disregard multi-character matches). Equivalently, convert all matches captured to group 2 to an empty string (i.e., disregard matches not captured to group 2). [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/41EuUq/1)

Answer (score 3):

The negative lookbehind is not likely to be your issue as they [are supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) on almost all current release browsers. However JavaScript regex doesn't recognise `\K` as a meta sequence but rather as a literal `K`. You can work around that using this regex:

```
\b([a-z])\1+(?!\1|\b)|(?<=([a-z]))((?!\2)[a-z])\3+
```

This matches **either** `\b([a-z])\1+(?!\1|\b)`:

- `\b` : word boundary
- `([a-z])` : a letter, captured in group 1
- `\1+` : one or more repetitions of the captured letter
- `(?!\1|\b)` : lookahead assertion that the next location is not another repetition of the captured letter or a word boundary

**or** `(?<=([a-z]))((?!\2)[a-z])\3+`:

- `(?<=([a-z]))` : a positive lookbehind for a letter, captured in group 2
- `((?!\2)[a-z])` : another letter which is not the same as the previously captured letter, captured in group 3
- `\3+` : one of more repetitions of the captured letter

The first part of the regex will capture repeated letters at the beginning of a word; the second part captures repeated letters in the middle or at the end of a word.

You can then replace with `$1$3` which will replace any repeated letter matched by the regex with just a single copy of itself.

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BOYx0c/1)

In JavaScript:

```js
console.log('aaa baaab xxx fjjj'.replace(/\b([a-z])\1+(?!\1|\b)|(?<=([a-z]))((?!\2)[a-z])\3+/g, '$1$3'))
console.log('ahhj aaab cc iiik'.replace(/\b([a-z])\1+(?!\1|\b)|(?<=([a-z]))((?!\2)[a-z])\3+/g, '$1$3'))
console.log('bbb ahhj aaab cc iiik xxx fjjj baaaaaab yyyaaa'.replace(/\b([a-z])\1+(?!\1|\b)|(?<=([a-z]))((?!\2)[a-z])\3+/g, '$1$3'))
```

PHP demo on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/piVCo)

Comment: You provided an awesome explanation, very helpful. But the other answer provided a shorter, easier and more efficient way to solve this problem. Thank you anyway my friend.

Comment: @Samul no problem at all, you should always use the answer that works best for you. I agree that the other answer is indeed shorter and more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
let result = str.replace(/\b((.)\2+)\b|(.)\3+/g, '$1$3');
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/S5J5a6/1)

Comment: Very clever but could use a little more explanation...

Comment: Your solution does not work with special chars. For example `"ççç bbàà áá ãããã çç cççããc kkl iooop".replace(/\b((.)\2+)\b|(.)\3+/g, '$1$3');` does not work as expected.

Comment: @Samul: change the pattern to `/(?<!\p{L})((.)\2+)(?!\p{L})|(.)\3+/gu`

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite `(?<=^| )` as `(?:\s|^)` and keep that match in the replacement instead of using `\K` which is not supported in JavaScript.

You could write the pattern as:

```
((?:\s|^)([a-z])\2+)(?=\s|$)|([a-z])(?=\3)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:\s|^)` Match either a whitespace char or assert the start of the string
  - `([a-z])\2+` Capture a single char a-z in **group 2** and repeat matching that same char 1 or more times
- `)` Close group 1
- `(?=\s|$)` Positive lookahead, assert either a whitespace char or the end of the string to the right
- `|` Or
- `([a-z])(?=\3)` Capture a single char a-z in **group 3** while asserting the same character directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YG00j9/1)

```js
const regex = /((?:\s|^)([a-z])\2+)(?=\s|$)|([a-z])(?=\3)/g;

[
  "aaa baaab xxx",
  "ahhj aaab cc iiik",
  "#$aa$aa#aaa bbb"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s.replace(regex, "$1"))
)
```

---

If you want to match any letter:

```
const regex = /((?: |^)([\p{L}\p{M}])\2+(?= |$))|([\p{L}\p{M}])(?=\3)/gu;
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LH61YB/1)